# How do you identify when an image is done downloading with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am using form input to change the source of an img tag on the fly. I want to put an ajax loader in place of the image until the image is done downloading, and then replace the loader with the new image. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no jQuery to know when an image was loaded.

```
    // show animation that indicates image is loading
    var test = new Image();
    test.onload = function () {
        // this gets called when the image has loaded
        // we need to place the image on the page:
        $('#ImageContainerWhatever').append(test);
        // and hide the loading animation
    };
    test.src = 'my_image.png';
```

`onload` is called when the browser loads the image it doesn`t matter if from the web or local cache.

See those examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to the `load` event of an image.

Comment: That would be `$(image).load(function ...)` but I really don`t see the need for jQuery at all here, the _two_ characters you save from typing `on` (in IMG's `onload`) get countered by the _three_ characters `$()` and the overhead of using jQuery.

Comment: I would use `addEventListener`.